# Unable to import swagger into aws api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway, swagger-2.0

I'm using swagger 2.0 and it works fine with my server but I'm unable to import the same YAML/JSON file into AWS API GATEWAY. I get a number of errors when I upload the file . How should I use the Swagger with AWS API GATEWAY?

I get the same errors when I try to integrate from swaggerhub integration with AWS.

Comment: Can you share your Swagger template? It would also be helpful to know which errors you're encountering

Comment: There are several known issues with swagger support in API Gateway, There is a section in the "Known issues" page which lists them http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html